# How can I get data after click on text with AJAX jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I used this code for sending and returning result.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.special').click(function(){
            var info = $(this).attr("rel");
            //$(this).html(sku);
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url:"../ajax/addSpecialFlag.php", 
                 async: false,
                 data: {info:info},
                success:function(result){
                    $(this).html(result);
                }});       
        }); 
    });    
</script>

<b style="cursor: pointer" class="special"  rel="<?=$v['number']."/*".$v['vid']; ?>">Special</b>
```

**addSpecialFlag.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['info'];
?>
```

This code should return "Info" in "<-b class='special' ->" but no returning result. Where is the problem ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you inspected the request using Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: try adding `error` handler to your `ajax` call.  That could shed some light on what went wrong....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be that `$(this)` inside your `success`-handler is not the same as outside of the handler. Doing it like this should solve your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.special').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var info = $this.attr("rel");
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url:"../ajax/addSpecialFlag.php", 
             async: false,
             data: {info:info},
             success:function(result){
                $this.html(result);
            }});       
    }); 
});
```

Comment: That's important. Note that not `$(this)` but `$this` can be called anything you want, like `this_first_this`. I'd leave out the dollar sign or it can be confused with jquery's special pathways to itself via `$`.

Answer (score 0):

`<b>`? Umad? Please use `<strong>`.

I have tidied your code so the paranthesis match their line indents and adjusted your success handler. The issue was the success handler is in a different scope to the click function scope so you needed to refer to it in another way, i.e. by assigning it to another variable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.special').click(function () {
        var info = $(this).attr("rel");
        var _this = $(this);
        //$(this).html(sku);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../ajax/addSpecialFlag.php",
            async: false,
            data: {
                info: info
            },
            success: function (result) {
                _this.html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```